# How to push additional fields to a javascript array from an oData result

Tags: javascript, arrays, odata, sapui5, metadata

I have a ramdom array in javascript

```
var dataModel = [];
```

I've queried an oData url and I want to fill the result in my dataModel [] array. And, for each item I want to add additional fields

```
odataMod.read(
        "/",
        null, [],
        true,
        function (oData, oResponse) {
            var data = oData.results;

            data.forEach(function (item) {
                //Add the object 
                dataModel.push(item);
                //I want to add additional fields to every object in data 
                dataModel.push(item.ObjectType = "Chevron");
                dataModel.push(item.HierarchyNodeLevel = 0);
                dataModel.push(item.IsCriticalPath = false);
                dataModel.push(item.IsProjectMilestone = false);
                dataModel.push(item.DrillDownState = "expanded");
                dataModel.push(item.Magnitude = 5);

...
```

Note : the ObjectType , DrillDownState , Magnitude  (etc...)  are the fields that I want to add with their values Chevron, 0, false (etc...)

Below  is a screenshot of the current result :

[image]

But I want to add the additional properties inside each item and not outside , what I am doing wrong? In other word, I want the additional fields to be inside the metadata

Below is a sc of where I would like to add the items :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I think you want only one push per item in the response.  The other pushes ought to be replaced with setting properties on a copy of the item...

```
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            item.ObjectType = "Chevron";
            item.HierarchyNodeLevel = 0;
            item.IsCriticalPath = false;
            item.IsProjectMilestone = false;
            item.DrillDownState = "expanded";
            item.Magnitude = 5;
            dataModel.push(item);  // note: just one push

            // alternatively, so as to not mutate item...
            // const dataModelItem = Object.assign({
            //    ObjectType: "Chevron",
            //    HierarchyNodeLevel: 0,
            //    etc.
            // }, item);
            // dataModel.push(dataModelItem);
        }
```

Comment: You're not misunderstanding, it's exactly what I was looking for :) ! Thanks

Comment: Note that Object.assign is not available in IE. Also I don't think a copy of the item is necessary, since the original item object will not be used afterwards.

Comment: @Marc - thanks.  agree that the more common approach is to mutate the received object which would otherwise be discarded.  Edited to show that way as the default, with my original non-mutating alternative in comments